# Is there a way to make a histogram normalized not to unity but to a specific value of choice?

Tags: histograms

I am trying to create a histogram that is normalized to a value other than 1, so this wouldnt work for me:
Histogram[list,"PDF"]

Comment: Just curious:  Why do you want it normalized to something other than 1?  Also, your code  doesn't get a PDF but rather warning that PDF is not a proper bin specification.  You might want to use `Histogram[list, Automatic, "PDF"]'.

Comment: That's what i was using, i want to normalize to something different than unity because that graph is showing a specific percentage of events that where counted so i need it normalized a that percentage instead of 1.

Answer (score 6):

As described in the documentation for Histogram, the third argument can be a function that accepts two arguments, bins and counts, and returns a list of desired heights. To calculate the total area of bins, you multiply each of the bin width with the corresponding counts. Then you use this as a normalization for bin heights.

```
norm = 4;
Histogram[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100000], Automatic, norm * #2/((Abs@*Subtract @@@ #1) . #2) &]
```

[image]

If you will use this many times, you can assign this function to a new symbol, for example:

```
normPDF[norm_] := norm*#2/((Abs@*Subtract @@@ #1) . (#2)) &;
```

then use it as

```
Histogram[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100000], Automatic, normPDF[4]]
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Ill use this one, I can't upvote you yet sadly. I was reading the description and searching for something useful for hours.